# Finite difference computation blowup from intel compiler 14, but not 12

Tags: vectorization, icc

I have a finite difference code for wave propagation, because there is a lot of temporary mixed derivative term, I defined a temporary memory buffer and separate them into chunks to store each derivative term for memory efficiency. The code looks like

`Wrk = malloc(2*(4*nxe*(2*ne+1) + 15*nxe)*sizeof(float));`

computing function:

`float *dudz   = Wrk + NE;`
   `float *dqdz   = dudz   + nxe;`

`for (int i=ix0_1; i<ixh_1; i++)`
     `dudz [i] = hdzi*(u[i+nxe]-u[i-nxe]);`

The problem for me, is that the code runs fine with Intel compiler 12, however it will blow up when compiling it with intel compiler 13 and 14.
All the compiling from intel compiler 12, 13 and 14 will optimize the code above by vectorizing the loops. If I turn off the compiler optimization for intel compiler 13 and 14, by defining 
  `volatile float *dudz   = Wrk + NE;`

The code will also run fine although slower.

I would greatly appreciate if any of you could give me some advice,
Thank you so much,

```
                        gqchen
```

Comment: Do you mean the code build with ICC 13 or 14 will result in wrong results when the compiler optimization is turned on? From the information you shared above, I am unable to comprehend what "u" array and "hdzi" are. Could you please provide more information on this (it will be great if you can share the code snippet here). We have an article which describes how to optimize 3D finite difference code on Xeon Processors and Xeon Phi Coprocessors: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/eight-optimizations-for-3-dimensional-finite-difference-3dfd-code-with-an-isotropic-iso

Comment: "u" is a array, which is used to calculate "dudz", "hdzi" is a temporary variable.  The reason I ignore the other part of code is that they are all similar to the loop above. Thanks again for answering my question,